# Can I set a timeout for a few seconds when connecting to a 3rd party via a form post?

Tags: asp.net

During a form submission, I have to verify something and I don't want to wait for more than a few seconds.

I.e. if I don't get a response within 5-10 seconds, just end the request.

Is this possible and reliable?

I am doing a server side XML post in C#.

Comment: Can you detail your architecture a bit? On which part do you wish to set the timeout? The client<->server, or the server<->*3rd-party*?

Comment: How are you "verifying something"? With a web service call? DB query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code-behind's Init event:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 10;
```